# How do I invoke this most basic usage of csplit?

Tags: text-processing

For a while I've wanted to learn how to use `csplit`, so tonight I tried practicing. I created a file with some text, and where I wanted to split the text, I wrote two colons (::) surrounded by two newlines, so that they formed separate double-spaced paragraphs from the rest of the text. Then I invoked `csplit` thus:

```
$csplit filename /::/
```

I thought I had failed when I saw that the only thing printed to standard output was some numbers. But when I looked at the directory listing I realized I had partly succeeded. One bunch of text had been cut off from the rest, the top bit. I just needed `csplit` to notice the other places where I had put two colons. But I couldn't figure out how to do that. I thought it might be

```
$csplit filename /::/*/
```

but alas, that did not work.

Persuant to an answer below, I also tried

```
me@localhost:~/folder$ csplit story3.bkp /::/'{*}'
```

but I got

```
csplit: /::/{*}: integer expected after delimiter
```

so then i tried adding a space after /::/ -- which worked!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking for `csplit file /::/ '{*}'`?

Comment: 'fraid no cigar. amended question to reflect.

Comment: nevermind. i just figured it out -- there's a space in between / and ', which the se markup doesn't show well in my browser. thanks...